# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (480,640,3) into shape (480,640)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, valueerror

So I'm trying to do fft, and here is my code

```
def fftImage(img_gray, rows, cols):
    rPadded = cv2.getOptimalDFTSize(rows)
    cPadded = cv2.getOptimalDFTSize(cols)
    imgPadded = np.zeros((rPadded, cPadded), dtype=np.float32)
    imgPadded[:rows, :cols] = img_gray
    img_fft = cv2.dft(imgPadded, flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
    return img_fft
```

img_gray is obtained using cv2.imread

```
img_gray = cv2.imread("/content/hinh1.jpg")
    # 1.fast Fourier transform 
rows, cols = img_gray.shape[:2]
img_fft = stdFftImage(img_gray, rows, cols)
```

```
def stdFftImage(img_gray, rows, cols):
    fimg = np.copy(img_gray)
    fimg = fimg.astype(np.float32)   #Notice the type conversion here
    # 1.Image matrix times(-1)^(r+c), Centralization
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            if (r+c) % 2:
                fimg[r][c] = -1 * img_gray[r][c]
    img_fft = fftImage(fimg, rows, cols)
    return img_fft
```

And the error is

```
---->     img_fft = stdFftImage(img_gray, rows, cols)

--->      imgPadded[:rows, :cols] = img_gray
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (480,640,3) into shape (480,640)
```

So how do I fix this simple error? Thanks, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Number of elements in your input array must be equal to elements of output array. for example if you are reshaping a 3-dimentional picture from shape (480,640,3) into 2-dimentional picture, your output shape could be (1440,640) or something like that.
In another word 480*640*3 should be equal to (a,b) which herr, a & b can be 1440 and 640, respectively.
I hope I could help you.